# Only a small portion of the data is uploaded to the server - Ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, php-5.6, php-7.1

I am using following ajax request to send data to my backend API (written in PHP).

```
$.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data:({
            type: 'save',
            data: DATA
        }),
        ........
```

here, the "DATA" is a 2D array which has 700 entries. An example of data is shown below,

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Mac1
            ....
            .... 
            [26] => Single
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Mac2
            ....
            .... 
            [26] => Single
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Mac3
            ....
            .... 
            [26] => Single
        )
   .............
```

Problem is, when I upload data in the local environment (checked with php 5.6 and php 7.1 both) it works fine (all 700 entries are uploaded), But when I use a server (which has PHP 5.6) it only uploads up to 37th entry (out of 700 entries only 37 entries are getting uploaded ).

I tried the same on a server which has PHP 7.1 and it worked fine. I have two questions

1. What can be the reason for not working in PHP 5.6 server?
2. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: the only problem seems is `post_max_size` and `max_execution_time`. compare this in both `php5.6` and `php 7.1`

Comment: I would try to stringify the data first - `JSON.stringify(DATA)`, then decode it in PHP `json_decode($_POST['data'])`

Comment: thank you for your response. Both php.ini configurations in local environment and server environment are same.

Comment: Why don't you jump to PHP7?

Comment: Hi @Derpanel is there any performance improvement when using JSON format?

Comment: I ask to compare `server (which has PHP 5.6) ` and `server which has PHP 7.1`.Not local and sever

Comment: @MAChitgarha I cannot move with php 7. Since some clients use PHP 5.6

Comment: @AlivetoDie But he said local PHP5.6 also working fine right?

Comment: @AlivetoDie both php 7.1 and php 5.6 server also have the same configurations for php.ini

Comment: In local environment for both php 5.6 and php 7  it works fine

Comment: @ChanakaR PHP7 can receive more requests than PHP5.6. It may related to this. See: http://talks.php.net/froscon15#/drupalbench

Comment: @ChanakaR I'm not sure about performance. The main difference is that with JSON, the `data:DATA` will pass as a single form data entry, as opposed to `data[]=xxx&data[]=xxx&data[]=xxx`. Just see if it solves your problem before worrying about performance.

Comment: @ChanakaR Also take a look at this: http://talks.php.net/vienna17#/wpbench

Comment: Thanks @MAChitgarha. But it is not the solution to my problem. I cannot go with PHP 7.1

Comment: There's an ugly way; you can make 20 AJAX requests, contains 35 entries each.